# MANOVA effect size (partial eta squared) in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, anova, manova

For ANOVA, one can easily get the partial eta squared (`np2`) effect size with `effectsize::eta_squared`:

```
> model <- aov(mpg ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
> effectsize::eta_squared(model)
For one-way between subjects designs, partial eta squared is equivalent to eta squared.
Returning eta squared.
# Effect Size for ANOVA

Parameter   | Eta2 |       90% CI
---------------------------------
factor(cyl) | 0.73 | [0.57, 0.82]
```

Furthermore, while conducting **MANOVA** in SPSS, one can get `np2` easily for each DV by simply checking the "Estimates of effect size" box.

[image]

[image]

However, trying to get the `np2` for each DV in R:

```
> model <- manova(cbind(mpg, hp) ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
> effectsize::eta_squared(model)
# Effect Size for ANOVA (Type I)

Parameter   | Eta2 (partial) |       90% CI
-------------------------------------------
factor(cyl) |           0.46 | [0.28, 0.57]
```

Or yet:

```
> heplots::etasq(model)
                eta^2
factor(cyl) 0.4564352
```

Only outputs a single `np2` (for the global model?), rather than a separate effect size for each DV.

Documentation for `?eta_squared` notes:

> for mlm / maov models, effect sizes are computed for each response
> separately

But this is obviously not the case here. Yet, when I check class of object, it includes class `maov`:

```
> class(model)
[1] "manova" "maov"   "aov"    "mlm"    "lm"
```

One could of course rerun an anova for each effect size by defining separate models:

```
> model <- aov(mpg ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
> effectsize::eta_squared(model)
Parameter   | Eta2 |       90% CI
---------------------------------
factor(cyl) | 0.73 | [0.57, 0.82]

> model <- aov(hp ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
> effectsize::eta_squared(model)
Parameter   | Eta2 |       90% CI
---------------------------------
factor(cyl) | 0.71 | [0.55, 0.80]
```

Or write a `lapply` call for each model:

```
aov.list <- list(model1 <- aov(mpg ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars),
                 model2 <- aov(hp ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars))

lapply(aov.list, effectsize::eta_squared)

[[1]]
Parameter   | Eta2 |       90% CI
---------------------------------
factor(cyl) | 0.73 | [0.57, 0.82]

[[2]]    
Parameter   | Eta2 |       90% CI
---------------------------------
factor(cyl) | 0.71 | [0.55, 0.80]
```

But it doesn't seem to be the most efficient. Surely, there is a way to do this from `effectsize::eta_squared`?

### Question

How to get the partial eta squared for MANOVA in R for each DV the correct way?

Comment: No, there's not a way to do this directly with `effectsize::eta_squared()`.  But you can easily get eta squared from individual ANOVAs by doing `lapply(summary(aov(cbind(mpg, hp) ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)), eta_squared) `.

Comment: @27ϕ9 if you'd like to propose this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit the multivariate analysis of variance model using `lm` instead.
You then have the option to access partial effect sizes for individual variables or globally.

```r
options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly"))
model <- lm(cbind(mpg, hp) ~ factor(cyl), 
            data = mtcars)
# Compute effect size variable by variable
effectsize::eta_squared(model, partial = FALSE)
#> # Effect Size for ANOVA (Type I)
#> 
#> Response |   Parameter | Eta2 |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------------------
#> mpg      | factor(cyl) | 0.73 | [0.57, 1.00]
#> hp       | factor(cyl) | 0.71 | [0.55, 1.00]

# Compute MANOVA statistic and global effect size
mtest <- car::Anova(model)
effectsize::eta_squared(mtest)
#> # Effect Size for ANOVA (Type II)
#> 
#> Parameter   | Eta2 (partial) |       95% CI
#> -------------------------------------------
#> factor(cyl) |           0.46 | [0.28, 1.00]
#> 
#> - One-sided CIs: upper bound fixed at [1.00].
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>